# confirmation message is not firing a href onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

below is only a part of my javascript code. confirmation message is not firing.

```
 function PKId_delete_formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="JqGridClients/Delete?id=' + cellvalue + '" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></a>';
}
```

I think the above code is enough, please let me know if more code is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
return '<a href="JqGridClients/Delete?id=' + cellvalue + '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure want to delete?\');" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></a>';
```

It inserts the proper quotes for the `confirm`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BS5u6/1/

Comment: Great! it works fine. can you please explain why do i need to use backslash